# Jquery Selectors Why add a space?

Tags: jquery, css

Messing about with Jquery and wondered why there is a space in selectors.
If I have list like this:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li class="a">item </li>
    <li class="b">item </li>
    <li class="c">item </li>
    <li class="d">item </li>
</ul>
```

And I want to select all **li** items with  class **a** ill do this:

```
$('li.a');
```

But if i want to select all class **b** items but within **ul** tag i write it like this:

```
$('ul .b');
```

Why is there a space?

Comment: The space does the equivalent of `find`. e.g. `$('ul').find('.b');` if that makes it clearer :)

Comment: I recommend that you do a tiny little bit of research by yourself before posting anything.

Comment: oh come on my question wasnt that bad

Comment: @Jack But you haven't shown any research effort

Comment: [Descendant Selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

Comment: I didn't know how to phrase my question on google

Comment: See the topic "CSS Selector".
[CSS Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Comment: @Jack I won't judge. Just learn the basics of CSS before going much further with jQuery. It will help a lot.

Comment: @Erik Yes good Idea im pretty new to this stuff so im jumping right in

Comment: @Jack That's right. You're getting confused with selectors, which are actually a CSS thing. Javascript/jQuery is confusing enough. Learn CSS first, when the penny drops with CSS selectors, there's one barrier overcome in learning jQuery.

Comment: @Jack can you accept an answer if your question is answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing this:

```
$('li.a');
```

you matching li tags with a class

```
$('ul .b');
```

This code will match ul tags and within ul tags all elements with b class

hope it helpfull.

Answer (score 3):

To denote that you're selecting items within. Not items with.

So you're selecting li with the class "a" in the first case, and all items with class "b" that are inside a UL in the second case.

It's very different selection logic.

Answer (score 2):

`li.a` select the `li` elements with class `a`.

`ul .b` select the elements with class `b` which has a `ul` as ancestor.

*(`ul > .b` select the elements with class `b` which has a `ul` as **parent**.)*

Answer (score 0):

The space is here to explain that the element with class b is inside the ul element.

You will find lot of information about CSS selector (jQuery use it) [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

`$('li.a')` means all `li`s with class `a`;

`$('ul .b')` means all the descendants of `ul` which have the class `b`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('li.a'); // it will select li with a class

 $('ul .b');   it is like  $('ul').find('.b');  // select child element  of ul
```